# Book involved a young girl who wants to be a doctor or scientists and ends up working in a lab

Tags: story-identification

A girl wasn't normal in her time considered this book was placed in an old time period. I remember she discovered why everyone kept getting sick and it was because the maid who cooked the food didn't wash her hands properly and prepared the food. She also started to grow feelings for her "boss" in the lab who also defended her when a man was trying to be with the girl. Anyone know the book?

Comment: Please go through the questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and edit as many answers to them as you can into your question to give us more details. Also, what was the fantasy/science fiction part of the story?

Comment: If this doesn't have SF elements, you might try asking it instead at http://literature.stackexchange.com